# NEC code requirements for clearance of outdoor receptacle

Tags: electrical, receptacle, outdoor

I'm planting full-grown trees from a nursery along the perimeter of my property. There is an existing outdoor receptacle on the concrete barrier dividing my property line about 6-12" above the ground level. I want to plant a tree in front of it or to the side. I'm wondering what minimum clearance the receptacle needs to be kept compliant.

I'm in California btw with a home originally built in the 1970s.

Comment: I suppose if it gets to close to a tree then it becomes...a branch circuit.

Comment: Leave enough space to reach it easily.  Remember trees increase their diameters as they grow, it is slow, but maybe an extra foot diameter in 20/30 years(probably more years).  You don't want to depend on a six year old every time you want to plug something in.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact  Since it's only one receptacle, it can't be a trunk line.